# How to compress Kotlin projects in Android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I create one android application in android studio and for programming language i used **Kotlin**.
Now my application finished and i want build my app, but after build app show me **35mb** for application size!!!
My **drawable folders** size has **2mb** and not have any larger size file, but why my application size is **35mb** ?!!!

For generate test apk version i used **Build -> Build bundle/Apk -> Build apk** from android studio menu.

But when use **java** for language this size is **7mb**!!!

How can i fix it?

Comment: use Vector Images or webp

Comment: This size you're mentioning sounds huge to me. I suggest using android studio to examine the contents of the apk. Generate that file, then go to file menu and there's an option there to look inside the apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some random ideas to improve your apk size:

- Turn on minification (ProGuard or R8, use the property `minifyEnabled`), recheck your ProGuard files if you are not excluding too much
- Convert your images to `webp` files, or vectors, which are even better
- Add an `abiFilter`, which excludes ancient ABIs, such as `mips`
- Use Android App Bundles, which splits the apk per language, ABI and screen resolution, essentially reducing the delivered APK size
- Check if you have any libraries you don't use anymore
- Filter out any unsupported languages with the `resConfigs` attribute

Android also has a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size) about this, which goes into more detail.

Comment: Thanks but why in java size is 7mb ?

Comment: The Kotlin library is quite large, and maybe you have no proguard enabled